# Manual ISO control and Zoom control in Android L camera (android.hardware.Camera2)

Tags: android, android-camera

Here I am  in trouble with new Camera API (`android.hardware.Camera2`). In my application, I want to set Manual ISO control and Zoom control on camera but I don't know how to do that. I know that I need to change the following:

1. `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` for ISO.
2. `LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH` for zoom.

But problem is, there are only definitions and descriptions on android developer site and no examples that how to declare and use these methods while coding.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The `LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH` for zoom only works for phones with optical zoom, which is quite rare compared to the number of Android phones out there in the wild. To zoom in using the Camera 2 API, you should do the following.

1. Determine the maximum digital zoom using the following snippet.

```
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mCameraManager
        .getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
Float maxDigitalZoom = characteristics.get(
        CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM);
```

2. Create a cropping `Rect` for digital zoom and use it while previewing AND capturing a still image.

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, cropRect);
```

and

```
mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice
        .createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, cropRect);
```

**NOTE** You are responsible for determining and implementing zoom controls. For each zoom level create the appropriate `cropRect` and its dimensions cannot be smaller than `floor(activeArraySize.width / android.scaler.availableMaxDigitalZoom)` and `floor(activeArraySize.height / android.scaler.availableMaxDigitalZoom)`.

You can retrieve the `activeArraySize` using the `CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE` key.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the example from android developer website][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/index.html you will see that you need to set parameters as you build your `CaptureRequest`:

```
 mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
```

You should do the same with the parameters you want to set, ie.

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH, desiredValue);
```

Comment: How can I get deiredValue ? Is it ontouch value? How to implemnt if I have zoom seek bar?

Comment: You decide what the `desiredValue` is. I don't know how it works with a zoom seek bar.